# Trouble understanding the meaning of w1=w|w|

Tags: regex, math, regular-language, dfa

Alright so I have a language L={w:|w|≥1,and w1=w|w|}.

w1=w|w| are w subscript 1 and w subscript |w|.

Im confused with what w1=w|w| means.
|w| means the length of w, but if we're setting w1 as in the first word to the
|w|th word in the language, then what is that exactly? When we say |w| here the length of which word are we talking about?

Comment: I'm guessing it means that L is the language of words of length at least 1 whose first and last letters are the same, such as `dad`, `druid`, and `denied` but not `dog`, `ddr` or `coddled`.

Comment: Probably it would be a better question if you could attach an image (photo or something) of how this definition really looks like. Currently it is very hard to guess.

Answer (score 0):

> Alright so I have a language L={w:|w|≥1,and w1=w|w|}. w1=w|w| are w subscript 1 and w subscript |w|.

Given that the 1 and the |w| are subscripts, what this means is that L is the language of words w of length at least one (|w| ≥ 1) whose first and last symbols are the same. Given your description, no other interpretation seems more likely than that.

Such a language is regular for any alphabet A. Suppose A = {a1, a2, ..., an} is any alphabet (so n ≥ 1). A regular expression for your language is given by (a1)((A*)(a1))* + (a2)((A*)(a2))* + ... + (an)((A*)(an))*. A DFA would have this transition table:

```
q    s    q'
---  ---  ---

q0   a1   q1    // remember the first symbol
q0   a2   q2    // by moving to a unique state
...  ...  ...   // per symbol
q0   an   qn

q1   a1   q1    // q1 is accepting and q1' is not
q1   A\a1 q1'   // move between these and only
q1'  a1   q1    // accept if the last thing seen
q1'  A\a1 q1'   // is a1

q2   a2   q2    // q2 is accepting and q2' is not
q2   A\a2 q2'   // move between these and only
q2'  a2   q2    // accept if the last thing seen
q2   A\a2 q2'   // is a2

...

qn   an   qn    // qn is accepting and qn' is not
qn   A\an qn'   // move between these and only
qn'  an   qn    // accept if the last thing seen
qn'  A\an qn'   // is an
```

This DFA has 2n + 1 states. We can use Myhill-Nerode to argue that it is minimal by showing that each of these states represents a different equivalence class and that no other different equivalence classes exist (under the indistinguishability relation).

1. the empty string is distinguishable and corresponds to state q0.
2. all length-one strings are distinguishable and correspond to states q1 through qn.
3. all length-two strings consisting of two different symbols are distinguishable and correspond to states q1' through qn'.
4. strings of length 2 or longer that begin and end with the same symbol are indistinguishable from length-one strings corresponding to states q1 through qn.
5. strings of length 3 or longer that begin and end with different symbols are indistinguishable from length 2 strings corresponding to states q1' through qn'.